# How to pass textbox in mustache json

Tags: jquery, default, mustache

how can i pass input tag in json using mustache template?

```
<input type='text'name='userProfile.user.firstName' id='firstName' value="" 
class="formMediumTxtBox"/>
```

am getting a syntaxerror as '}' missing.

any soluitons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, it was a jquery error from my side
sorry for the inconvenience